# Need HELP! with - SQL Plus Select multiple columns

Tags: sql

Hi I am using sql plus and I need to select 5 columns from 4 tables and show the result. This is the code that i used and the error I get.

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderID, AircraftID, Quantity, TotalCost 
FROM Customer_Table, Order_Table, Aircraft_Table, Orderline;
```

> ERROR at line 1:  ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

What is the code to get these columns and display them from multiple tables. Please help with this.

Comment: You realize you are performing a cross-join on 4 tables?

Comment: yeah but I need code to help show the results from the four tables, do you know how.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is  that you tried to execute an SQL statement that joined two or more tables, where a column with the same name exists in both tables.

**Exemple with this SQL query**

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, quantity
FROM suppliers, orders
WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id;
```

Since the supplier_id column exists in both the suppliers and orders table, you need to prefix the column with the table name as follows:

Moreover you need to link your tables between them. If I take the example above you should do this kind of thing

```
WHERE suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id;
```

Means you link the table `suppliers` with the table `orders` by the column `supplier_id`

This article may help you to understand about your issue:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SQL plus specifically but in most SQL variants you should specify a table name then a column name. Such as SELECT Customer_Table.CustomerID ...... this will disambiguate which column should be used in the result projection.

Comment: This worked but the thing is that it ran a never ending loopselect Customer_Table.CustomerID,Order_Table.OrderID,Aircraft_Table.AircraftID,Orderline.Quantity,Order_Table.TotalCost FROM Customer_Table,Order_Table,Aircraft_Table,Orderline;

Comment: The cross join you created is cause the size of the return set to be the number of rows for table 1 times number of rows for table 2 times .... It will eventually end...

Answer (score 0):

The error means one or more of those columns exist with the same name in those tables. Thats why it does not know which column to select from what table. If you could specify the table name and then the column, I think this should go away.

Comment: This worked but it ran a never ending loop, how do I make it stop with a result e.g. like a table showing the information fullstop. Please.
select Customer_Table.custID,Order_Table.Order_ID,Aircraft_Table.airID,Order_Line.Quantity,
Order_Table.Total_cost FROM cust,Order_Table,airbuy,order_line;

Comment: you a doing a CROSS JOIN, which essentially means doing a Cartesian product. and so it is going to take a long time to complete if you have many rows.

Comment: what should I do, should I do 2 columns with 2 tables and then do the same with the other 2 columns and 2 tables.